# Use of IP address in a cookie. Java jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I have a Jsp page, over which I have a modal to include a login feature as a form which on form submission goes to the servlet through doPost(REST). I am attempting to get the client IP address from the login HttpServletRequest in the servlet and send it back to the jsp in the HttpServletResponse.

To authenticate all the other forms requests in my Jsp, after successful login, I am attempting to create a new cookie in the jsp with the IP address in the login response from the servlet as the cookie value.

In the subsequent form requests, I am attempting to match the client IP address in the form HttpServletRequest in the servlet with the IP address in the new cookie (which will also be a part of the request and should be same as the client IP address during login). If the IP addresses match the request will be authenticated and executed.

Is this a good idea?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea because you can't get the origin IP of the client ( request through the gateway or modify by someone). Is better if you using spring security oauth2 for authentication user. After login success users have a session and using it for next time until it's expiry. (If users active on the browser, you should using [authorization code](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/authorization-code/#:%7E:text=The%20authorization%20code%20is%20a,approve%20or%20deny%20the%20request.) template in Oauth2)